# Manipulate the DOM of an IHtmlString property in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dom-manipulation, ihtmlstring

I'm making a ASP.NET MVC application using the Bootstrap framework. I got a property named `Content` type of `IHtmlString`.

```cs
public IHtmlString Content { get; set; }
```

This data comes from my database and is not well responsive for on a website.

**Example:**

The value of the property is this:

```html
<H3>Inhoud</H3>
<P>De opleiding klauwverzorging omvat een avond theorie en drie zaterdagen praktijk. In deze praktijkopleiding komen volgende onderwerpen aan bod:</P>
<P>•&nbsp;Bouw en ziekten van de ondervoet
  <BR>•&nbsp;Bestrijding van kreupelheid
  <BR>•&nbsp;Klauwverzorging op levend vee + persoonlijke veiligheid</P>
<P>
  <H3>Praktische Info</H3>
  <P></P>
  <P>Tijdens de opleiding maken we gebruik van 4 klauwverzorgingsboxen, evt. aangevuld met de klauwbox van het gastbedrijf. Daarnaast kan u gebruik maken van een uitgebreid aanbod aan mesjes, tangen, slijpschijfje, ...</P>

  <P>
    <IFRAME height=251 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DrEqvsiNtgg?rel=0;modestbranding=1" frameBorder=0 width=447></IFRAME>
  </P>
```

I know that this code isn't correct there is a `p`-tag not close etc.

My question is can I use an methode to query select the `iframe` and do my thing with it? I'll something equivalent to this JavaScript code

```js
document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
document.getElementsByTageName('iframe');
```

I've read the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx) but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Do you want to manipulate it on the server?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes I'll do this.

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)